# Filter push notifications in chrome to show only specific keywords

Tags: google-chrome, filter, push-notification

I want to filter the push notifications in google chrome so that only the ones with specific keywords show for me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more elaborate in your question. Please show what you have tried so far, and what problems you experienced. SO is here to help you solve a problem, but you have to do the work first.

Comment: Im not a dev im just asking for help

Comment: Not a problem, Still, SO is not a service where you can ask somebody to write code for you. You are most welcome to google for your specific problem and find support sites that can help you out. This platform is specific for problem solving where you encountered a problem and ask for help and you can provide what you have tried to accomplished the task. Please refer to the help section of SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Best of luck